# Yaml linting failling when jinja is used

Tags: salt, jinja, yaml

I am using https://yamllint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html to lint my yaml files (used in a saltstack context, and linted by jenkins jobs at every commit), but as reported and explained [here](https://github.com/adrienverge/yamllint/issues/61), it is not possible to validate a yaml file in which is used jinja code.

How do you guys validate / lint your yaml files ?

Do you see a way to keep using yamllint without failing due to jinja code ?

Yaml structure error are the most occuring errors in my company, people from very different background come to edit pillar, that's why I really need a yaml validating process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I was searching using the wrong keyword, I just found out that ignoring a file or dir is quite easy, you just need to add an gitignore style block to your yamllint config file, as :

```
ignore: |
  *globalParamName.sls
  *platform.sls
```

See the official doc [here](https://yamllint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html#ignoring-paths).

Answer (score 0):

One tool I have used in the past is [this](https://cryptic-cliffs-32040.herokuapp.com/) which does a great job of rendering YAML/JSON and allows you to inspect the resulting output in order to validate.

Answer (score 0):

I just run the code, e.g. Ansible or kubectl and if the yaml is incorrect these tools point out the line that contains the error. I never use a separate tool for validation the yaml.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new tool available with Salt 3005 - [`yaml.lint`](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.yaml.html)

```sh
salt-call yaml.lint salt://example/bad_yaml.sls
```